plotly comes up blank
This is a new issue I am having with plotly (gglot plot works fine) in Rstudio. Every time I try to make an interactive graph, it comes up blank. There are no error signs at all! Quick examples below in which ggplot works fine and plotly fails. I have installed and accessed plotly out of the library.
ggplotly( ggplot(Icecream) +
  aes(cons, price) +
  geom_point(col="black") +
  stat_smooth(method = lm)) 

blank, though it used to work.
ggplot(Icecream) +
    aes(cons, price) +
    geom_point(col="black") +
    stat_smooth(method = lm)

still works

This a known issue and most likely the same as in ggplotly produces a blank plot. See the comments on this post for a fix.

Interesting development: I recently updated to R 4.4 Puppy Cup and that was the issue. I downgraded to 4.3 and now plotly works. I wonder if others have that issue as well. Is something up with 4.4? I would enjoy hearing people's experiences and feedback.
